# Product slug not working in CRM 2013 Email templates

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a business requirement that execs are really wanting to see. In our lead and email templates we have a few of our products listed. The products themselves are pretty stable but the prices are of course subject to change.

I'm OK with hard coding the product name into email but I was hoping the price could be a slug that get's resolved.

We only have one price list so nothing to worry about there.

I see no way to get access to the product and or price list entities through the data field values dialog.

So my thought was to create the 2-4 fields in the lead and opportunity entities. Then create a background workflow that takes the price from the price list and sets those fields.

Then when an email is generated I can access those hidden fields as they will be available through the lead or opportunity entity.

Any thoughts, concerns, better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CRM's email template system is not capable of what you describe out of the box. As you have discovered it will only permit you to insert placeholders from, or assocated with, the primary entity.  It won't let you insert fields from other entities.  What you suggest as a workaround is possible but it's not an ideal solution as you'll have these 2-4 redundant fields on each record type that contain duplicated data from the price list.

If you have any experience with creating custom workflow activities using the SDK then the best solution here is to create a custom activity that accepts either an draft Email or Email template as a input parameter, instantiates the email if required, loads the price list data, and performs your own custom placeholder replacements.

I've done this on a few projects in order to pass multiple entity records into the template, or to insert complex tables into emails by loading data from relationships.  See the screenshots below for an example of how I've configured the email template and dialog process to pass both an 'Account' and 'User' record into the email template.

[image: CRM email template placeholders]

[image: email dialog]